# How do I bind the Textbox from List?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need only to bind the Textboxes. I created a next and previous button this works but nothing is on the Textbox. What do I wrong? How do I get the items form the List?

The Read from the Database:

```
   void read()
    {
        using (var nwe = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {

            var objctx = (nwe as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
            ObjectQuery<Employee> query = new ObjectQuery<Employee>(
                "SELECT VALUE n from NORTHWNDEntities.Employees as n", objctx);
            List<Employee> results = query.ToList();


            cursor = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(results);

        }
    }

    private void countposition()
    {
        labelRead.Content = "Read " + (cursor.CurrentPosition + 1) + " to " + cursor.Count; 
    }
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(cursor.CurrentPosition < cursor.Count -1)
        {
            cursor.MoveCurrentToNext();
            countposition();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No more data");
        }
    }

    private void buttonPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         if (cursor.CurrentPosition > 0)
         {
            cursor.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
            countposition();

         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("No more data");
         }

    }
```

The UI Code to Bind the Data:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="163,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeID}" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelFirstNAme" Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxFirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="163,157,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelLastName" Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLastName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="163,224,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelBirthDate" Content="Birth Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.289,0.462" Width="67"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxBirthDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="163,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=BirthDate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145"/>
```

Comment: This is not related to sq-server, please use tags properly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I drank a few beers but TextBox accepts just one value, id est typically .Text="oneStringInstanceOnly". 
You would like to bind List<> (that has multiple values / objects / strings / classes) to a TextBox that accepts generally one (usually string) value and that is the reason why you cannot bind a List that contains multiple values to a TexBox that accepts one value. TextBox is not a DataGridView or ListBox that accept multiple values / data tables. Evenutally you could assign the TexBox with the first value from the list myTextBox = (myList!=null && myList.Count!=0)?myList[0].ToString():"NoMoreValues";